# Animate tableview cell when deleting

Tags: swift, uitableview, animation

I have a tableview. The tableview cell contains images, labels. In this cell I have a button to delete the row. I want to animate the cell during deletion(ex. tinder like left or right swipe) or any animation to make the app actractive. How to do this type of animation. Or any recommended library ?

Comment: Typically, you just remove the object associated with that row from your model and then call [`tableView.deleteRows(at:with:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614960-deleterows), supplying the `IndexPath` of the row being deleted and the desired animation, which will result in the animated deletion of the row.

Comment: can I delete the row with animation like tinder ?

Answer (score 1):

`UITableViewCellEditingStyle` will do the job for you for i.e

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .delete {
        //do your necessary operations here
        //reload your UITableView here
    }
}
```

Swipe right to left to see the animation.

Answer (score 1):

Typical Animation for your case :

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .delete {

        // your code

        tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)

       // your code

    }
}
```

Alternate Way for custom Animation **(Updated)**:

```
tableView.beginUpdates()
tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .top) // Check (.)after for available animation example comment   out below -
//tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([YourIndexPathYouWantToDeleteFrom], with: .left)
//tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([YourIndexPathYouWantToDeleteFrom], with: .right)
//tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([YourIndexPathYouWantToDeleteFrom], with: .up)
//tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([YourIndexPathYouWantToDeleteFrom], with: .down)
//tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([YourIndexPathYouWantToDeleteFrom], with: .fade)
//tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([YourIndexPathYouWantToDeleteFrom], with: .middle)
//tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([YourIndexPathYouWantToDeleteFrom], with: .bottom)
tableView.endUpdates()
```